# CakePHP GroupBy and Sum on a Virtual Field?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

CakePHP's virtual fields thing is limited when working with associated models, I know that. However.

I've got a system that I want to work out hours per Project, then hours per operation for that project. I have a table that contains "Logs" which are created when people have clocked in and out of a project. Then a table called projects that is related to this table. The logs records have a field called "Operation" which dictates what they were doing on the job.

Cake's built in behaviours filter the records so it only shows the current project's Logs. I've made an "on the fly" virtual field that works out the total minutes that a user has been logged on to a Project. That's all working fine.

What I want to know is, can I do a Sum on the "minutes" virtual field, then group by the Operation.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$this->Project->ProjectLogs->virtualFields['minutes'] = 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ProjectLogs.in, ProjectLogs.out)';
$prep = $this->Project->ProjectLogs->find('all');
```

This works correctly, I just need to group and total up the virtual field 'minutes'.

Can you do this with virtual fields?

Answer (score 1):

As it's a virtual field, you can't use that virtual field (minutes) to sum the data (as another virtual field). You need to redefine the virtual field inside your sum function:

```
$this->Project->ProjectLogs->virtualFields['minutes'] = 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ProjectLogs.in, ProjectLogs.out)';
$this->Project->ProjectLogs->virtualFields['sum_of_minutes'] = 'SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ProjectLogs.in, ProjectLogs.out))';
```

You can then group your query:

```
$prep = $this->Project->ProjectLogs->find('all', array(
    'group' => 'Operation'
));
```

This may seem repetitive... Well no, it *is* repetitive. Since you're essentially constructing an SQL query with PHP, you can reuse that VF definition using PHP to shorten the repetition factor:

```
$minutes = 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ProjectLogs.in, ProjectLogs.out)';
// use $minutes now instead of duplicating
$this->Project->ProjectLogs->virtualFields['minutes'] = $minutes;
$this->Project->ProjectLogs->virtualFields['sum_of_minutes'] = 'SUM(' . $minutes . ')';
```

Comment: Any ideas, even though I'm using the relationship, as to why it isn't just bringing to active projects logs, but the whole table?